# Mysql Workbench bugs on gui auto increment, foreign key changing, datatype

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm working on MySQL Workbench Version 6.1 (6.1.4.11773 build 1454). I see too bugs in Workbench. But there are issue only on using gui. There are no bug or issue with codes, query so manually. I cant change auto increment with checkbox of alter table. But i can change with codes. I can't set foreign key without codes. There is a checkbox issue of setting foreign key referenced column. But I can set same foreign key with codes. And When I set a Datatype look like "INT(11)", It's working but then It's looking this "(11)". I see a lot of thing like these. Are these bugs?

Comment: I'm tempted to vote for closing this question as it is not a real programming question nor does it have enough information to give you any useful answer. Try improving your question. Add images (screenshots) to show what you think is a bug. Focus on a single issue at a time (one question for auto inc, one for datatype display) etc.

Comment: I see you have asked a separate question about the INT data type already (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276172/mysql-workbench-integer-datatype-bugint-changes-11). So, change this one to go more into detail for your other problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you run mysql workbench in Turkish locale, it will not work correctly. Create a table with "INT" fields. Then save it. then try to alter the table. it will only display (11) as the field type. Because in Turkish locale, i and I are different letters. (corresponding to ı and İ) and this causes a problems while trying to create foreign keys. because it cannot find any columns with type (11).

Go to your **Server->Options File** and change these options to

1. Character-server-file => utf8
2. Collation-server => utf8_general_ci

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276172/mysql-workbench-integer-datatype-bugint-changes-11) before, I could only solved the issue with changing the "Regional format" setting of Windows 10 OS from "Turkish (Turkey)" to "English (United states)".